# does image extension matters in django projects (like jpg and png)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

am trying to load static and adding image in my project and I get this error ***"GET http://localhost:8000/static/kpn.jpg 404 (Not Found)"***  please I need your help

Comment: It's probably paths but we can't test on `localhost`, unfortunately :)

Comment: Hello. You should put your folder structure and your projet configuration. You cannot be helped if we do not how you do things.

Answer (score 0):

1- configure `STATIC_URL` on your `settings.py`:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
    './staticfiles',
)
```

2- add `STATIC_URL` to your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
                ...
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```